# LWC setCustomValidity on lightning-input-field

Tags: lightning-web-components, required-field, lightning-record-form, lwc-dom

I'm using a `<lightning-record-edit-form>` with `<lightning-input-field>` children.

When required fields are not populated, it occurs the standard message "**Complete this field**".

What I want to do is to edit it with a custom message, but unfortunately it's not possible through the `setCustomValidity()` function (as the `<lightning-input>` has).

Is there another way to achieve this?

Thanks, Davide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Custom Error Message On Input field]

> ```
> As workaround what you can do is set up a validation rule for that field and throw it field level so as to throw a custom error message.
> ```

In the below example I am throwing error at Email field of contact whenever I try to create one and my custom error message appears.

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Contact">
        <lightning-messages>
        </lightning-messages>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Name">
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Email">
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" type="submit" label="Create new">
        </lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
```

[image: validation Rule on contaact email field]

Comment: Thanks for your response. This could help, I just have to understand how much effort could take to maintain it.

Comment: if it helps can u upvote.